# How to train and save multi class artificial neural network model using tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to train a multi class classification neural network model using tensorflow. So I have 24 feature vectors that's in the form of numpy array that looks like this when I print it:

```
[[1 0 0 ... 0 1 1]
 [1 0 0 ... 0 1 1]
 [1 0 0 ... 0 1 1]
 ...
 [1 0 0 ... 2 0 0]
 [1 0 0 ... 2 0 0]
 [1 0 0 ... 2 0 0]]
```

Above is the `x_train` dataset that I want to train. It has a shape of

```
(10799, 24)
```

Then the `y_train` dataset looks like this

```
[   307    307    307 ... 257947 257947 257947]
```

And it has a shape of:

```
(10799,)
```

So `y_train` as a label contains different classes, the number shown there are the IDs. And it has a total of 480 classes. So far my attempt in training this is like this:

```
#Normalize the data
x_train = x_train/x_train.max()

#Convert the y_train to be one-hot encoded because they're not a regression problem, to do categorical analysis by Keras.
from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_cat_train = to_categorical(y_train)

#BUILDING THE MODEL
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(24,input_dim=24,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=48,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=96,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=192,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=384,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=420,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=450,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(480,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

#TRAINING THE MODEL
model.fit(x_train,y_cat_train,epochs=25)

#SAVING THE MODEL
model.save('myModel.h5')
```

But then I get an error saying:

`ValueError: Shapes (None, 257948) and (None, 480) are incompatible`

Can anyone teach me or explain how to use tensorflow properly to train and save the model for multi class classification? And please explain what I did wrong in the code and possible solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide `input_shape` parameter

```py
#Normalize the data
x_train = x_train/x_train.max()

#Convert the y_train to be one-hot encoded because they're not a regression problem, to do categorical analysis by Keras.
from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_cat_train = to_categorical(y_train)

#BUILDING THE MODEL
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Dense(24, activation="relu", input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],)),
        layers.Dense(48,activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(96,activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(192,activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(384,activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(420,activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(450,activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(len(set(y_cat_train)), activation="softmax")
    ]
)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

#TRAINING THE MODEL
model.fit(x_train,y_cat_train,epochs=25)

#SAVING THE MODEL
model.save('myModel.h5')
```

NOTE:
With a network that contains more than 3 `Dense` layer, you have to increase the number of `epoch` in order to get the network converge.

In my opinion is better to start with only 1 layer that have the size of the number of features in input, and then modify the network.

In your case, it will be better start with a single layer that contains `len(x_train.shape[1])`.

Avoid to use (when possible) numpy array as X,y. Instead, cast the data using the `Tensorflow` tf.Data structure.

You can refer to the following code example:
https://github.com/alessiosavi/tensorflow-face-recognition/blob/90d4acbea8f79539826b50c82a63a7c151441a1a/dense_embedding.py#L155